# After a user hits the submit button, how do I make an image or icon appear over another image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This question is for a website coded in HTML.

mapquest image

*I pulled the above image from google (located on mapquest.com) and I do NOT own this image. With that said, please look at this picture as a reference to go along with my question. Assume that this image does not start with the star, only appears after the user clicks the submit button.

How would I code in html (assuming jquery or javascript) to let a user check a box. Example: Categories: Shoes ▢ [SUBMIT]

Then after pressing the submit button, changing an image to have an icon on the imagemap appear such as the star. I want this where it has multiple available categories and after the user checks the boxes for the categories and clicks submit. Either the image completely changes to show the icons (star, or whatever I want for the icon), or it simply leaves the image and just adds the icon over the image.

Edit: I am adding this in to hopefully narrow down what it is that I am looking for in response to this question. I do not need my hand held if you do not wish to go through line by line, but even a link would suffice. Thanks.

I am looking for more specific details on how to code this. I don't think it would be as efficient to change the entire image every time, so how can I drop the icons on the image using something like an imagemap, so it drops at the appropriate coordinates over the image? Like if you searched on google maps and the icons drop onto the image (obviously not something as complex, but you get the idea).

Current HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Welcome | xxxxxx.com </title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body style="margin:0px; padding: 0px;">
<div class="container">
  <div class="header"><img src="images/bg_header1.png" width=950px usemap="#Map" border="0"/>
    <map name="Map" id="Map">
      <area shape="rect" coords="475,28,572,71" href="#" alt="about" />
      <area shape="rect" coords="609,27,746,71" href="#" alt="locations" />
      <area shape="rect" coords="783,27,894,73" href="#" alt="contact" />
      <area shape="rect" coords="55,23,278,61" href="index.html" alt="home" />
    </map>
  </div>
  <div class="content"><img src="images/parismap1.fw.png" width=950px/>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"><img src="images/bg_footer1.fw.png" width=950px/></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML + any attempt you've made at the JS?

Comment: Normally a submit button takes you to another page. So this involves coding both your HTML and jQuery code then?

Comment: I just need help on where to begin looking for a solution to the jQuery in the HTML. I have not made any attempt on the jQuery for this functionality as I do not know where to begin. I usually can find an answer on google, but I don't know what functions to look into..

Comment: Post your HTML atleast?

Comment: Take a look at the .submit() event in jQuery. http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: I posted my HTML, but it doesn't have anything to do with dropping any icons on the image yet. Okay, I'll take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the way I understand your question, there are a few things you need to do in order to dynamically add icons on top of an image. Here's the way I would do it.

First off, a good way to move icons around on top of an image without changing the image is to use CSS's `position` rule.

In your image div, set its position to relative, and the icon's to `position:absolute`, like so:

```
#imageDiv
{
    background: url("/images/image.png");
    position: relative;
}

#iconDiv
{
    background: url("/images/icon.png");
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Then by adjusting the `top` and `left` rules, you can move the icon anywhere inside of the image div. *(Note that these can also be substituted with **bottom** and **right**)*

Hopefully I don't need to tell you you'll also need to **give each of the divs a height and a width rule** in order for them to show up.

**MAKE SURE YOUR ICON DIV IS *INSIDE* OF YOUR IMAGE DIV**:

```
<div id="imageDiv">
    <div id="iconDiv">
    </div>
</div>
```

Secondly, you'll need a javascript function to adjust the CSS rules. If you want it to be in a form using a submit button, you'll also need to return false on the submit function so it doesn't take you to the `action` page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(){
        //Update CSS Here in a way similar to this:
        $("#imageDiv").css({"top":someValue+"px", "left":someOtherValue+"px"});

        return false;
    }
}
```

That is one way to do it. Hope that helps.

**NOTE: You'll need jQuery for this solution!**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll have a go with what you are saying and look into what the others are saying as well. I'll jump back on here later to follow up.